# span should have 9 li

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Iam trying to make thymeleaf page into angular js .Below is my code

```
    </ul>
<ul class="list">
  <span class="columns">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

Each span should have 9 elements. after that another span should be open. But right now all items are in single span.

Comment: missing a lot of information on this question

Comment: And at which point are you stuck?

Comment: There is no problem specified here

Comment: modulo to the rescue.

Comment: I think inside ul should be as child only li elements like here <ul><li><span>1</span></li><li><div>2</div></li></ul>

Comment: you have put ng-repeat inside <li> so it will repeat <li> not <span>

Comment: your code has a invalid syntaxe for [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-UL).

Comment: @ViniciusDutra — And every other version of HTML, including the current one.

Comment: Well the page was first made by using thymeleaf. I am trying to make it in angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- An `<li>` element can only be a child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.
- The only children a `<ul>` can have are `<li>`

… so you *can't* group them with span elements.

If you want to organise them in groups of 9 for rendering purposes, then consider using CSS grid (and setting up the `ul` as a grid with 9 columns).

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #afa;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x<li>x</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you can make a new array out of `list`:

```
let newList = [];
let tempList = [];
for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    tempList.push(list[i]);
    if (i%9 === 0) {
        newList.push(tempList);
        tempList = [];
    }
}
```

`newList` will be like this:

```
[
    [
        obj1,
        obj2,
        obj3,
        obj4,
        obj5,
        obj6,
        obj7,
        obj8,
        obj9,
    ],
    [
        obj10,
        obj11,
        obj12,
        obj13,
        obj14,
        obj15,
        obj16,
        obj17,
        obj18
    ],
    [
        obj19,
        obj20,
        obj21,
        obj22,
        obj23,
        obj24,
        obj25,
        obj26,
        obj27
    ],
    so on...
]
```

and then you can use this newly formed array to suit your purpose

```
<span ng-repeat="item in list" class="columns">
    <li ng-repeat="item2 in item">{{item2.name}}</li>
</span>
```

However, as many people have mentioned here, you should be using `<ul>` to group your list element like so:

```
<div class="columns">
     <ul ng-repeat="item in list" class="list">
          <li ng-repeat="item2 in item">{{item2.name}}</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I haven't tested the code but you should get the idea.

Comment: Inline elements can not contain block elements. Span is an inline while `ul` is a block element.

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` element is not valid content for `<ul>` elements.

From the Docs:

> The HTML `<ul>` element represents an unordered list of items, typically rendered as a bulleted list.
>
> - **Permitted content:**   zero or more `<li>` elements, which in turn often contain nested `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements.

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference: `<ul>` Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)